# Entity relationship for Questionn and Answer model

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, entity

I am creating entity for Question and and Answer in Java.So far i was able to design Question Entity.But  i can not understand how can i design an Answer entity.Think about a mcq qustion.An mcq question can have one answer or multiple answer.so how can create an Answer entity with muliple option.

Here is my question entity

```
 @Entity
 public class Question extends BaseModel {

 private String title;
 private String description;
 private String imagePath;
 private User  user;  /// user who asking the question
 private Integer rating;



 --------getter and setter
}
```

Now,What will be the answer model and how can i relate it with Question entity.

Comment: you can take `private List<Answer> answers` which is `@OneToMany` relationship which your  `Question` class

Comment: and `private Answer correctAnswer` which is  `@OneToOne` relationship

Comment: see this https://github.com/oojorgeoo89/QuizZz is the quiz project using spring boot which helps you ..

Comment: for single and multiple answers you required to configure `private List<Answer> correctAnswers` annotated with `@OneToMany`

Answer (score 0):

You can use one to many mapping

```
@Entity
class Question{
 .
 .
 @OneToMany
 @JoinColumn(name="ans_id")
    private Answer ans;
}

@Entity
class Answer{
 .
 .
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="ans")
  private Set<Question> question;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

one question can have many answer so the relationship is one to many

```
 @OneToMany
@JoinTable(name = "question_answer", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "Question_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "answer_id")})
private Set<Answer> answers = new HashSet<>();
```